# Bind getActivity().findViewById() using Butterknife

Tags: android, butterknife

Is that possible to do getActivity().findViewById() using `@Bind`. I want to bind view in another fragment using this way. But so far it can only be done in standard way :

```
Button mSubmit = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit)
```

Comment: You can achieve this using create ViewHolder class. @Azizi

Comment: try this: `Button mSubmit = Butterknife.findById(getActivity, R.id.btnSubmit)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but it seems like using [the two argument form](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/javadoc/butterknife/ButterKnife.html#bind-java.lang.Object-android.app.Activity-) of `ButterKnife.bind` would work -- pass `getActivity()` as the 2nd argument.

(I suspect this may have already been answered -- if someone wants to find an existing answer, please do.)